# Making Sure my Google Analytics Views are Set Up Properly

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, event-tracking

I have a Google Analytics property for our University's main website - www.williamwoods.edu - and I am trying to set up a view for one of our subdomains.

We have one set up already for our News site - news.williamwoods.edu. This new one is going to be for our University President's personal blog - presidents-corner-blog.williamwoods.edu.

I've mimicked the setup for the News site for the Blog site, since the numbers for that site seem fine. It has our regular GA tracking code set on it and had the view set up in GA. I'm guessing that this is because we consider it a Property of the main williamwoods.edu domain.

The problem, though, is that the President's Corner Blog view doesn't seem to be reflecting *specifically* pages on the presidents-corner-blog.williamwoods.edu subdomain. If I go to Behavior, Site Content, All Pages while under this view, I can see URLs that reflect the structure of the main williamwoods.edu domain.

Am I using Views correctly? Should I set them up differently? Or, might it just take some time for the View to reflect the specific Subdomain associated with it? If it can be of use, here is how I have my views set up:

[image]

Any suggestions on how best to set up GA so that I can track traffic on the different subdomains would be greatly appreciated. :)

Thanks!

Comment: If you don't get too much traffic, you can either include the hostname in the "page" dimension OR track the subdomains as separate properties in the account. Using filters and views to do this might not be the best choice for your use case.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I think I may have found another angle to this as well - the News site is using an SEO plugin to set the Analytics code on the page, so I've set up the President's Blog to do the same - instead of having it in the base files. I'll keep an eye on it over the next couple of days and see if this makes any difference. :)

Comment: Hi Will, the method of implementation shouldn't affect the filters/views. Assuming the implementation was done correctly.

Comment: @XTOTHEL - you're right - the real reason it wasn't recording correctly was because I hadn't escaped the hyphens in "presidents-corner-blog" in the filter for the view. Now, though, I have a separate issue. We are also wanting a general "blog.williamwoods.edu", and the view for that is picking up anything with "blog" in the subdomain - so the President's Corner, the "mba-blog", etc. This makes me think that Properties are going to be the way to go after all. Unless there's a way to tell it "explicitly, the string 'blog' followed by string '.williamwoods.edu'" in the RegEx for the filter...